# Android--How to construct a layout that when a component hide,another component can cover it

Tags: android, android-layout

The demand is that:

- There is a listitem, and I want to add two component (a imageview,a
  checkbox)to it.
- In the default case,the imageview is shown, when I longclick the
  listitem,the imageview is set invisible and the checkbox is visible

I wanna construct the layout of the listitem in an appropriate way, I tried the relativelayout which consists the two,and set the both `android:visibility=gone`, but it doesn't work.
I guess the problem exists in the following aspects:

1. The fields of the relativelayout is wrong, and then how to write it?
2. Should try other layout like framelayout?

The listitem layout is as follows:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="72dp"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ibClinicMessageLeft"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"

    />

<!-- item中的text,subtext和时间 -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llTotalText"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ibClinicMessageLeft"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvClinicMessagetTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ibClinicMessageLeft"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textColor="@color/text"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvClinicMessageTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textColor="@color/hint"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvClinicMessageText"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvClinicMessagetTitle"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ibClinicMessageLeft"

        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textColor="@color/subtext"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</LinearLayout>



 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_toRightOf = "@id/llTotalText"
    android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height ="fill_parent"
    >

    < CheckBox
           android:id ="@+id/cbCheckBox"
           android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height ="wrap_content"
           android:visibility ="gone"
           android:clickable ="false"
           android:focusable ="false"
    />

<!-- item中的箭头图片 -->
       < ImageView
           android:id ="@+id/ivItemArrow"
                  android:src ="@drawable/im_arrow"

           android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height ="fill_parent"
           android:layout_centerVertical ="true"
                  android:layout_marginRight ="16dp"
           android:visibility ="gone"
           />



       </ RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, what you do is set the visibility of the imageview to VISIBLE, and not add any checkbox in the list view.

Then at runtime, in the List onItemClickListener, set the visibility of the imageview to INVISIBLE and instantiate a checkbox and set it to VISIBLE and also put it at the required position.

Something like this :

```
 CheckBox edt;

        edt = new CheckBox(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp =
    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
    (
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
lp.setMargins(25, 0, 0, 0); // move 25 px to right (increase left margin)
edt.setLayoutParams(lp); // lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
```

You can set margins to whatever your imageview was using.

Like this :

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv1);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams newparam = iv.getLayoutParams();
```

That's it.

Comment: since the checkbox isn't added to the listview,i'm a little confulsed about the "CheckBox edt = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.yourcheckbox);" ,where is the id from?
and actually the listitem contains 3 other component ,(a big linearlayout wrap the whole,the imageview and checkbox is in the 3rd place in the horizontal orientation)

Comment: Post your layout file.

Comment: And the id is from the layout file. 


Your checkbox must be having an id set like this : 



android:id = "@+id/checkBox"

Comment: i have placed my layout~~

Comment: You still don't get the answer?

The checkbox id is : cbCheckBox and the ImageView id is : ibClinicMessageLeft

Set the imageview invisible and set the checkbox visible with the same layout parameters so that it gets placed at the exact location where the imageview had been.

Comment: You still don't get the answer?

The checkbox id is : cbCheckBox and the ImageView id is : ibClinicMessageLeft

Set the imageview invisible and set the checkbox visible with the same layout parameters so that it gets placed at the exact location where the imageview had been.

Comment: i'm sorry. but there are several points i still can't get:  1,should the layout contains both checkbx and imageview? or should only contains imageview and then i add a checkbox dynamically?